# Scrapy: custom loggers appear to be overriding Scrapy loggers and silencing Scrapy logger output

Tags: python, web-scraping, logging, scrapy

I am in the process of trying to integrate my own loggers with my Scrapy
project. The desired outcome is to log output from both my custom loggers and
Scrapy loggers to `stderr` at the desired log level. I have observed the
following:

- Any module/class that uses its own logger seems to override the Scrapy logger,
  as Scrapy logging from within the related module/class appears to be
  completely silenced.

  - The above is confirmed whenever I disable all references to my custom
    logger. For exmaple, if I do not instantiate my custom logger in `forum.py`,
    Scrapy packages will resume sending logging output to `stderr`.
- I've tried this both with `install_root_handler=True` and
  `install_root_handler=False`, and I don't see any differences to the logging
  output.
- I have confirmed that my loggers are being properly fetched from my logging
  config, as the returned logger object has the correct attributes.
- I have confirmed that my Scrapy settings are successfully passed to
  `CrawlerProcess`.

My project structure:

```
.
└── scraper
    ├── logging.cfg
    ├── main.py
    ├── scraper
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── forums.py
    │   ├── items.py
    │   ├── pipelines.py
    │   ├── runner.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── spiders
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── forum.py
    │   │   └── someforum.py
    │   └── utils.py
    └── scrapy.cfg
```

The program is designed to be called from `main.py.`

Contents of `main.py`:

```
import os

from scraper import runner, utils
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

logger = utils.get_logger("launcher")


def main():
    """Entrypoint to the web scraper."""

    # Guarantee that we have the correct reference to the settings file
    os.environ.setdefault("SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE", "scraper.settings")

    logger.info("Initializing spiders")
    runner.run_spiders(get_project_settings())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Contents of `runner.py`:

```py
from scraper import forums, utils
from scraper.spiders.someforum import SomeForum
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

logger = utils.get_logger("launcher")


def run_spiders(project_settings):

    process = CrawlerProcess(project_settings, install_root_handler=False)
    logger.info(
        f"Initialzing spider for {forums.someforum.get('forum_attrs').get('name')}"
    )
    process.crawl(
        SomeForum,
        **forums.someforum.get("forum_attrs"),
        post_attrs=forums.someforum.get("post_attrs"),
    )

    process.start()
```

Contents of `logging.cfg`:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,launcher,forum,item,pipeline

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=basic

[logger_launcher]
level=DEBUG
handlers=basic
qualname=launcher
propagate=0

[logger_forum]
...

[logger_item]
...

[logger_pipeline]
...

# --

[logger_scrapy]
level=DEBUG

# -- 

[handlers]
keys=basic

[formatters]
keys=basic

[handler_basic]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=basic

[formatter_basic]
format=%(asctime)s - [%(name)s] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Note that I want to be able to configure module-level logging verbosity outside
of a Python file. That's why there's a random dummy logger for Scrapy in `logging.cfg`, so that I
can go grab it in the `settings.py` file and pass it to the underlying
`CrawlSpider`.

Contents of `settings.py` file:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read(LOG_CONF)

LOG_LEVEL = config["logger_scrapy"].get("level")
LOG_FORMAT = config["formatter_basic"].get("format")

BOT_NAME = "scraper"
SPIDER_MODULES = ["scraper.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "scraper.spiders"
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 8
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    "scraper.pipelines.PostPipeline": 300,
}
```

Function `utils.get_logger()`:

```
import logging

from settings import LOG_CONF
from logging import config

def get_logger(logger_name):
    """Returns logger"""

    # LOG_CONF just points to `logging.cfg` in root directory
    config.fileConfig(LOG_CONF)
    return logging.getLogger(logger_name)
```

If I run `main.py` with my `launcher` logger, the logging output will contain
stuff like:

```
2021-11-12 16:37:23,994 - [launcher] - INFO - Initializing spiders
2021-11-12 16:37:24,016 - [launcher] - INFO - Initialzing spider for someforum
2021-11-12 16:37:24,045 - [scrapy.extensions.telnet] - INFO - Telnet Password: 62df42034f3a7f09
2021-11-12 16:37:24,070 - [scaper.spiders.forums] - INFO - Creating scrape time log directory for forum: 'someforum'
2021-11-12 16:37:27,617 - [scraper.items] - DEBUG - Fetching post title
2021-11-12 16:37:27,617 - [scraper.items] - DEBUG - Fetching post currency
2021-11-12 16:37:27,617 - [scraper.items] - DEBUG - Fetching post price
2021-11-12 16:37:27,617 - [scraper.items] - DEBUG - Searching post title for tags
2021-11-12 16:37:27,617 - [scraper.items] - DEBUG - Fetching post hash key
```

If I run `main.py`, but remove my `launcher` logger from both `main.py` and
`runner.py`, the logging output will contain stuff like:

```
2021-11-12 16:39:37,734 - [scrapy.utils.log] - INFO - Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: scraper)
2021-11-12 16:39:37,735 - [scrapy.utils.log] - INFO - Versions: lxml 4.6.4.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:04) - [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021), cryptography 35.0.0, Platform macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit
2021-11-12 16:39:37,735 - [scrapy.utils.log] - DEBUG - Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-11-12 16:39:37,748 - [scrapy.crawler] - INFO - Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'scraper',
'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 8,
'LOG_FORMAT': '%(asctime)s - [%(name)s] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scraper.spiders',
'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scraper.spiders']}
2021-11-12 16:39:37,769 - [scrapy.extensions.telnet] - INFO - Telnet Password: 2baaa967d9d68933
2021-11-12 16:39:37,792 - [scrapy.middleware] - INFO - Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
```

Scrapy logging from my call to `CrawlerProcess.crawl()` is once again logged to
`stderr`, which is great. I just don't want my logs and Scrapy logs to be
mutually-exclusive.

My gut tells me I'm messing up the root logger somehow, or my own loggers are
overriding Scrapy loggers. I'm out of ideas on how else I can troubleshoot this,
so any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. **TLDR**: calling `fileConfig()` disabled all existing loggers by default, which is how I was instantiating my logger objects in my `get_logger()` function. Calling this as `fileConfig(conf, disable_existing_loggers=False)` resolves the issue, and now I can see logging from all loggers.

---

I decided to drill down a bit further into Python and Scrapy source code, and I noticed that any logger object called by Scrapy source code had `disabled=True`, which clarified why nothing was logged from Scrapy.

The next question was "why the heck are all Scrapy loggers hanging out with `disabled=True`?" Google came to the rescue and pointed me to a thread where someone pointed out that calling `fileConfig()` *disables* all existing loggers at the time of the call.

I had initially thought that the `disable_existing_loggers` parameter defaulted to `False`. Per the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig), it turns out my thinking was backwards.

Now that I've updated my `get_logger()` function in `utils.py` to:

```
import logging 

from settings import LOG_CONF
from logging import config

def get_logger(logger_name):
    """Returns logger"""

    config.fileConfig(LOG_CONF, disable_existing_loggers=False)
    return logging.getLogger(logger_name)
```

Everything works like a charm.